# Documentation for the gradle run task?

Tags: java, gradle

After a long time of searching I was still not able to find any official documents for the `gradle run` task. I assume that is because it is actually [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:jvmArgs) task type.

It also seems that the `run` task is only available with the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). Its docs mention some of the available arguments such as `--debug-jvm` and `--args` (for passing command-line arguments to the application's main method).

What I actually wanted to find out how I can pass arguments to the JVM on the command-line, i.e. an equivalent of setting `application { applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ".." }`.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Check out this one: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-command-line-arguments

Comment: Thanks! `--args="lorem ipsum dolor"` indeed is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the `run` task comes from the application plugin and it is a `JavaExec` task.

A list of all configuration options is available in the [documentation of the JavaExec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html)

You can configure options in your (groovy-)gradle file like so:

```
tasks.named('run', JavaExec) {
    mainClassName = '...MainKt'
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [ System.getProperty("jvmArgs") ]
    classpath = sourceSets.netMain.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now written https://blog.jakubholy.net/2020/customizing-gradle-run-task/ which describes both how to customize the `run` task and how to customize it on the command line:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "my.app.Main"

run {

  debugOptions {
      enabled = true
      server = true
      suspend = false
  }

  systemProperty("my.defaultLogLevel", "debug")
  environment("OTEL_EXPORTER", "zipkin")
  jvmArgs=["-javaagent:aws-opentelemetry-agent-0.9.0.jar"]
}
```

> As the application plugin documentation states, you can also enable debugging with --debug-jvm or specify arguments with --args="foo --bar". And you can set application { applicationDefaultJvmArgs= []} to apply both to run and the generated start scripts of your distribution.